# Get-ChildItem error handling when using long file paths

Tags: powershell

I am trying to handle errors when scanning through folders. Let's say I have something like:

```
Get-ChildItem $somepath -Directory | ForEach-Object {
   if(error occurred due to too long path) {
        skip this folder then
   } else {
       Write-Host $_.BaseName
   }
}
```

When I do this I print the folders in `$somepath` until one of them is too long and then the loop stops. Even when using `SilentlyContinue`. I want to print even after reaching a folder that is too long.

Comment: Don't ask your question again by double posting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572006/error-handling-a-too-long-path-in-a-foreach-object-loop-in-powershell

Comment: you could handle the exception: [System.IO.PathTooLongException]

Answer (score 6):

If you can install a non-ancient PowerShell version (3.0 or newer), simply prepend the path with `\\?\` to overcome the 260-character limit for full path:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\?\$somepath" | ForEach {
    # ............
}
```

Comment: I have to find a reference but I was under the impression this does not work anymore.

Comment: Likely in my ignorance but I get errors running this: `Illegal characters in path.` or `Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet.`....

Comment: PS5.1+Win7: https://puu.sh/rlaUh/748082bbdb.png and yeah it won't work in PS2 as I've just tried by running `powershell -version 2`

Comment: That part makes sense then. I'm on 10 running v5. Thanks  for the picture.

Comment: If anyone is curious for some documentation on this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could try ignoring the files longer 260 characters by using the `Where-Object` cmdlet.

```
Get-ChildItem $somepath -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
    | Where-Object {$_.length -lt 261} `
    | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.BaseName }
```

Or you could use the following ([Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697259/how-do-i-find-files-with-a-path-length-greater-than-260-characters-in-windows)).

```
cmd /c dir $somepath /s /b | Where-Object {$_.length -lt 261}
```

Comment: I wrote even when using SilentlyContinue :( Then it just doesn't print an error, but it does not print beyond that point.

Comment: This is not working for me.  I like the length idea, but don't we want to use `$_.FullName.length`?

Answer (score 0):

I will add my solution since the neither on this page worked for me.  I am using relative paths, so I can't use the `\\` prefix.

```
$TestFiles = Get-ChildItem $pwd "*Tests.dll" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.FullName.length -lt 261} | Select-Object FullName -ExpandProperty FullName | Where-Object FullName -like "*bin\Release*"
Write-Host "Found TestFiles:"
foreach ($TestFile in $TestFiles) {
    Write-Host "   $TestFile"
}
```